# Datatable Deferloading 10 rows out of 1000

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, html-table, deferred

I have an [API](https://jsonblob.com/57c09794e4b0dc55a4f0f369) that return 1000 accounts.
My goal is to load only my first 10 rows, and load more - if the user click on the `next`.

---

## HTML

**table**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

---

## JS

## Try #1

**config**

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/account_index',
            dataSrc: 'data'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'account_id' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'email' }
        ],
        "deferRender": true,
        "deferLoading": 10 <-----
    } );
```

---

I got

[image]

---

## Try #2

**config**

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/api/account_index',
            dataSrc: 'data',
            deferLoading: 10 <-----

        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'account_id' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'email' }
        ],
        "deferRender": true
        
    } );
```

---

I got all 1000 account listed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set length if you want to display only 10 records at a time.
add the below mwntioned attribute.

"iDisplayLength" : 10

Comment: Yes we can do this and also we might need to put the limit in query too, to fetch the next limit number of records

Answer (score 0):

I copied over the data to [myjson.com](https://api.myjson.com/bins/13ahl) and used datatables 1.10.12. It seems to work. Snippet below.

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/13ahl',
            //dataSrc: 'data'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'account_id' },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'email' }
        ],
    } );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I only want to load the 10 rows at a time, how would you do that ? You're very close.

Comment: Don't you have to use deferloading ?

Comment: Restricting each fetch call to 10 records has to be implemented server side and when serverside is set to true, all processing has to happen server side (paging, sorting, etc).
deferloading only tells datatables total count of records and to skip the initial request.

Comment: The question is to properly use `deferloading`, and your answer is not really cover what I am asking for.